# .draggable is not working on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have worked with `.draggable()` function before and it worked fine the previous time. However this time it is not even working. I have no idea why?

These are my jQuery links

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

**This is my HTML Code**

```
<div class="mainArea" id="response"> 
    <div class="designer">
        <?php include"shirtBasic.svg" ?>
        <div id="imageDiv"> </div>
        <div id="dragDiv"> </div>
    </div>
    <table width="100%" border="0" id="sizeBar">
        <tr>
            <td class="leftBarButton" style="width:50%">Front</td>
            <td class="leftBarButton" style="width:50%">Back</td> 
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and this is the jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#dragDiv').draggable();
    });
});
```

This is not the only code there is other code above and below HTML and jQuery as well but not relevant.

Please help me find the problem and suggest if I have linked the correct versions of jQuery, if there is a newer available please enlighten me.

Comment: Why are you including two versions of jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 honestly these versions and their names have always confused me please indicate the one to delete?

Comment: 2 versions of jquery may cause conflict. you should keep the first one. Don't delete the UI

Comment: @Claudiu and delete the second one? :/

Comment: Logic would say get rid of the old one (1.6.2), but without knowing more it's hard to say if that will break what you have.

Comment: we can't tell you what version of jQuery it's better for you, it depends on 1) what version of jQuery.ui you need, 2) what version of web browser you need to support (jQuery 2.x does not support IE8 and below) and 3) what are the jQuery functions your application uses

Answer (score 3):

Your code works well... http://jsfiddle.net/m6ac80wb/2/

You should use only one version of JQUERY. You can keep the latest one `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js`

Also, don't forget to import the `jquery-2.1.1.js` **before** the `jquery-ui.js`.

Comment: Im sorry for this stupid question. So looking at the code above i should only keep the first one and delete the second and the third version?

Comment: @AyubBukhari The second one is the UI, I would keep it (if it works). You can delete the third one.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek is there a 2.1.1 version of UI?

Comment: Sorry, I mean find a version that works with your version of jQuery (if needed). There isn't a `2.1.1` UI.

Comment: Updated the  fiddle with `jquery-2.1.1.js`. Works just as well

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

It works if you try it that way, and also your stylesheet was missing the ":" in the url, it is not the reason it wasn't working, but I thought I should point it out.